# Uninstalling php 5.3 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, zend-framework, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed php 5.3 manually by executing commands like make & make install. But I need to upgrade it to v5.5 therefore I deleted all the directories related to php5 using sudo command.

But when I run php -v Still I am getting

PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Jun 8 2015 05:53:32) Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

Please help me to remove

Comment: -- purge might be get rid of it - Solution should be there : http://superuser.com/questions/539402/completely-removing-apache-phpmyadmin-php-from-ubuntu

Comment: i have already execute the purge command but still it is not working. What I think may  help is that I need to find directory path of apt-get php5 installation and then make a soft link. But I really have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: If it's doesn't fix it I think you could try to ask in AskUbuntu section of StackExchange (StackExchange  top left --> SearchBar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below answer credit goes to Maythux

To uninstall something you installed from source, you would use cd back into the directory you built it from and then run sudo make uninstall but I don't think this will work with PHP since it doesn't have an uninstall.

So what you can do is to make a package from the existing compiled version you have and then you could install the new created package over the old one, and if this works you can remove it. First install checkinstall if you dont have it:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

Then run:

```
 cd php-5.3.29
 sudo checkinstall
```

Accept all the defaults.The result will be a phpXX.deb package, so try to install it, this will replace the old files from the compiled package:

```
sudo dpkg -i phpXX.deb
```

If this goes smooth then you are near to have it. Now purge the package:

```
 sudo apt-get purge phpXX.deb
```

What to do if this doesn't work

you should remove all files manually

```
locate php5
```

Then remove the files and install a new version with apt-get again